# Uploading File to dropbox using Laravel adds meta-data to file content unexpectedly

Tags: laravel, dropbox, dropbox-api

Im tyring to Upload File ( Image/text ) to my dropbox using Laravel Http client.

my code :

```
$params = [ "path"=> "/TEST/sometext.txt",
            "mode"=> "add",
            "autorename"=> true,
            "mute"=> false,
            "strict_conflict"=> false];

$address = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
$response = Http::attach( 'attachment', fopen(public_path().'/img/text.txt','r'), 'text.txt')
            ->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer SOMEKEYS',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg'=>json_encode($params)
            ])
            ->post($address);

            dd($response->body());
```

it sends successfully but the content of the file ( .txt ) was updated with some "metadata"

Original File:

```
some text dont edit..
```

File Uploaded to Dropbox:

```
--71df864b515ecbb345df5a9496afd21bb03093e0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="text.txt"
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: text/plain

some text dont edit..

--71df864b515ecbb345df5a9496afd21bb03093e0--
```

maybe its the same reason why if I upload image.. its corrupted..  What I am doing wrong.. thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot tell whats causing the problem, but did you look at this package, the use of it might help/solve your problem? https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aless55 yes, but I just dont see enough documentation with that package and im just trying to implement a simple upload.. I believe it would be too much to use a whole library for it.. maybe if I can't solve the problem my self.. I'll might give it a try..

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by not using Laravel's http client.. I just used bare php curl request..

```
$params = [ "path"=> "/TEST/background.jpg",
                        "mode"=> "add",
                        "autorename"=> true,
                        "mute"=> false,
                        "strict_conflict"=> false];
                        

            //The URL you're sending the request to.
            $url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';

            //Create a cURL handle.
            $ch = curl_init($url);

            //Create an array of custom headers.
            $customHeaders = array(
                 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx',
                 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                 'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.json_encode($params)
            );

            //Use the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option to use our
            //custom headers.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $customHeaders);

            //Set options to follow redirects and return output
            //as a string.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents(public_path().'/img/background.jpg'));

            //Execute the request.
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
```